# Change queue size of a ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I need to be able to change the size of the task queue of a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).  Of course, the BlockingQueue doesn't support changing the size, and the ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't support changing the queue.

So, the method I've come up with is to use [ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow%28%29), which gives me back a list of the Runnables that haven't yet been executed.  Then I can create a new executor with the desired queue size and re-submit all of the tasks.

The issue is with the tasks in progress at the time of the shutdownNow() call.  As far as I can tell from the javadoc, the executor will call Thread.interrupt() on all threads currently executing a taks.  I don't want my tasks to be killed.  This question may have been a long-winded way of asking how to write my tasks such that Thread.interrupt() won't have any effect?

Comment: "*Of course, the BlockingQueue doesn't support changing the size, and the ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't support changing the queue.*" => what makes you think so? Some implementations of BlockingQueue have variable sizes.

Comment: What implementations would these be?  I have read the javadoc for every known implementing class of [BlockingQueue<E>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), and none of them supports being both bounded and resizable.

Comment: The ones I was thinking about are unbounded.

Comment: If they are unbounded, they don't have a size.  My first statement "I need to be able to change the size of the task queue of a ThreadPoolExecutor" indicates that I need a bounded size, and that I need to change it.  Unbounded queues do not satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a mix of "shutdown()" (not shutdownNow()),  then polling with getPoolSize()/isTerminated(), you could (a) stop the existing the pool . Then (b) simultaneously (in a separate thread) a new queue with the desired size could be created. You would have a tradeoff here in terms of:  can you allow there to temporarily exist more threads than the desired number (while the first pool is shutting down).

Comment: This is the best idea I've had suggested yet, so I'll go ahead and flag it as the answer.  Thanks for the help javadba.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating extending the unbounded LinkedBlockingQueue with an implementation which enforce a capacity on the underlying unbounded queue. This gives you a resizable work queue for your thread pool.

First, you'll need to create the resizable implementation

```
class ResizableBlockingQueue<E> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<E> {

    private int maxCapacity;

    public ResizableBlockingQueue(int maxCapacity) {
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    public int getMaxCapacity() {
        return maxCapacity;
    }

    public void setMaxCapacity(int maxCapacity) {
        this.maxCapacity = maxCapacity;
    }

    @Override public int remainingCapacity() {
        return getMaxCapacity() - size();
    }

    @Override public boolean offer(E e) {
        if (remainingCapacity() <= 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.offer(e);
    }
}
```

and now you can use it like this

```
ResizableBlockingQueue<Runnable> executionQueue = new ResizableBlockingQueue<>(QUEUE_SIZE);
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(MIN_THREADS, MAX_THREADS, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, executionQueue);

// Need a bigger work queue
executionQueue.setMaxCapacity(BIGGER_QUEUE_SIZE);
```

As you can see, by this design, setting a smaller capacity will not remove existing work from the queue but will prevent new work from being enqueued until the queue size falls below the new `maxCapacity`

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You should use isTerminated() method to check Executor state but make sure before calling isTerminated method you should call shutdown() otherwise isTermainated method aleays return false.